# Form Model Binding on Nested Routes - Cannot PATCH - Returns MethodNotAllowedException on RouteCollection on Line 219

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, nested-routes

I am getting the `MethodNotAllowedException` error whenever I try to submit a `PATCH` request to my controller. It only occurs on my nested route, all other routes that run the `PATCH` request work great.

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('customers.aircraft','AircraftController');
```

my form:

```
Form::model($aircraft, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'action' => ['AircraftController@update', $aircraft->id]])
```

Each aircraft belongs to a customer. My URL looks like this:

```
example.com/customers/5/aircraft/6/edit
```

What I'm observing in the address bar when I get the error message is this:

```
example.com/customers/6/aircraft
```

I have determined that this cannot be caused by the controller, because the very first line in my `@update` method is `dd($request);` and it doesn't get that far. I assume the issue is that the route is not getting the information it needs to direct my request, it is obviously taking the `aircraft_id` and using it as the `customer_id`, but I cannot figure out how or why.

I have tried this:

```
Form::model($aircraft, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'action' => ['AircraftController@update', [$customer_id, $aircraft->id]]])
```

Thinking that it needed the `customer_id` to be sent through, but that didn't work. I'm pretty new to `Laravel` so I do expect this is just a lack of knowledge, however nothing on Stackoverflow, Laravel or Laracasts websites have helped me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Put() method :

```
Form::model($aircraft, ['method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'action' => ['AircraftController@update', $aircraft->id]])
```

for Route::resource, the update method url should be like this :

```
example.com/aircraft/6

public function update(AircraftRequest $request, $aircraft_id) 
{ 
   $data = $request->all();
   dd($data['registration']); 
   $request['registration'] = strtoupper($request['registration']); 
   $aircraft->findOrFail($aircraft_id)->update($request->all());
   return redirect()->action('AircraftController@show', $aircraft_id); 
 }
```

so try to send customer_id in hidden input.
Let me know if it works

Comment: still getting the same result

Comment: Could you show me your AircraftController@update method

Comment: public function update(AircraftRequest $request, Aircraft $aircraft, $customer_id, $aircraft_id)
    {        
  dd($request);
        $request['registration'] = strtoupper($request['registration']);
  
  $aircraft->findOrFail($aircraft_id)->update($request->all());
  
  return redirect()->action('AircraftController@show', $aircraft_id);
    }

Comment: I've only just added the $customer_id for troubleshooting and I've also tried without the AircraftRequest

Comment: Ok try again and tell me if it returns data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109341/discussion-between-andrew-fox-and-bkf).